# Generating a text file of strings in linux

Tags: linux

I need to generate text files of strings of 3 characters, with duplicate strings allowed. I've searched for a method to do this, but I can only find methods to generate completely random text. Since I'm still a newbie, I have no idea of how to proceed. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: Does "strings of 3 characters" mean strings of length 3 or strings containing combinations of 3 characters? If the former, what characters are allowed? If the latter, what should the lengths of the strings be?

Comment: What is wrong with random text?

Comment: I guess you want to generate combinations of 3 characters, which can be easily done. But please be more specific in what exactly you're trying to achieve and why what you did so far is not good enough. And also state the programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash to get combinations inefficiently:

```
a[0]=a; a[1]=b; a[2]=c;
for i in $(seq 0 26); do
  r1=$(expr $i % 3)
  r2=$(expr $i / 3 % 3)
  r3=$(expr $i / 9 % 3)
  echo ${a[$r1]}${a[$r2]}${a[$r3]}
done
```

A faster way:

```
a[0]=a; a[1]=b; a[2]=c;

for r1 in $(seq 0 2); do
  for r2 in $(seq 0 2); do
    for r3 in $(seq 0 2); do
      echo ${a[$r1]}${a[$r2]}${a[$r3]}
    done
  done
done
```